# Difference between Provider value in OLEDB conncetion string MSDASQL and MSDASQL.1

Tags: mysql, odbc, oledb, oledbconnection

I was trying to connect a SQL and mySQL database through OLEDB. In case of MySQL, my connection string was like:

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MySQL;Initial Catalog=information_schema;
```

or sometimes it will be like:

```
Provider=MSDASQL;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=MySQL;Initial Catalog=information_schema;
```

The same suits for SQL connection string also.

The provider information in the connection string differs `Provider=MSDASQL.1 and Provider=MSDASQL`.

I really don't know why the provider value differs. 
Why does it differ? Is there any reason behind this?

and an connection through `Microsoft OLE DB drivers for ODBC Drivers`.